# Measure Theories with a different convention to $\infty\cdot 0 =0$

Tags: measure-theory

As we all know in a first course in measure theory we define a symbol $\infty$ to satisfy $\infty \cdot 0=0$, but there are more two possible choices for a convention as someone has shown to me; one is $\infty\cdot 0 =\infty$ and the other $\infty \cdot 0 =-\infty$.

Can someone please provide references for those measure theories with a different convention than $\infty \cdot 0 = 0$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Arguably $\infty \cdot 0 = \infty$ is consistent with usual measure theory: the (usual Lebesgue) measure of a singleton subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is 0 but the measure of all of $\mathbb{R}$ is infinity.

Comment: @SamHopkins $\mathbb{R}$ is not a countable union of singletons, though.

Comment: I feel like any measure theory where you get rid of countable additively and insist all infinite sets have infinite measure is gonna be a very trivial theory...

Comment: @SamHopkins either way I'd like to see those theories. Some say all of maths when done correctly is trivial. cheers!

Comment: Finitely additive functions are certainly studied: see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma_additivity#Additive_(or_finitely_additive)_set_functions

Comment: Precisely where in measure theory you find this convention?

Comment: $\infty\cdot0 = \infty$ I can imagine, but $\infty\cdot0 = -\infty$?  Then $-\infty = \infty\cdot(0\cdot0) = (\infty\cdot0)\cdot0 = (-\infty)\cdot0 = -(\infty\cdot0) = \infty$, if multiplication is still associative (and, if not, then why not, say, $\infty\cdot0 = 1$?).

Comment: @LSpice so it seems that my friend who proved his argument was partially correct. Thanks for pointing it to me LSpice!

Comment: I think the precise convention needs to be explained a bit more; is it saying that the integral of the zero-function over a set of measure infinity is 0? Or that the integral of the infinite function over a set of measure 0 is 0? Or something else entirely?

Comment: @Alan I didn't vote to close but yes, it is not research level and should have been asked at math.stackexchange.

Comment: @NikWeaver ok, I won't ask anymore questions on overflow; I know when I am not welcomed.

Comment: @Alan I checked your activity history and it seems to me that you contribute a lot of value to mathoverflow, and the community here has shown its appreciation by giving you many upvotes. The current question isn't appropriate but I wish you wouldn't take that judgement too personally.

Comment: One of my answers was downvotes to oblivion, far worse than -2. Don't place more importance on this than it deserves.

Comment: So @LSpice am I right in saying we can take $\infty \cdot 0$ to be any number and thus we might get uncountable number of measure theories?

Comment: @NikWeaver sorry, this is my last post or thread in this cursed QA website. I will still ask and perhaps also answer questions in MSE, but for me mathoverflow is a forgotten memory.

Comment: @NikWeaver there are many questions here that are not research level though they don't get closed!

Answer (score 8):

It's not a convention, it's a theorem. Let's say I have a measure space $X$ and a function $f: X \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ which is identically zero off of a null set $N$, and constantly $+\infty$ on that null set. You can say that $\int f = 0$ ``by convention'', but you can also say that $\int f$ equals the area under the graph of $f$, i.e., the measure of the set $N\times [0,\infty)$. And that area has to be zero by countable additivity because the measure of $N\times [n, n+1)$ is $0\cdot 1 = 0$ for all $n$. The sum of infinitely many zeros has to be zero because that is what the partial sums converge to.

An instructive special case is the line $\{0\}\times [0,\infty) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Its measure is $0\cdot\infty$, right? Now for any $\epsilon$ find a sequence of rectangles which covers the line and whose areas sum to $\epsilon$. So this $0\cdot\infty$ has to be zero.

Comment: Another way to say it is that the integral of the given $f$ is zero no matter how you define $0 \cdot \infty$.  Adopting that convention just means that you can write a more compact expression for the integral of $f = c \cdot 1_A$, one which doesn't require $c=\infty$ or $m(A)=\infty$ to be special cases.  But measure theory doesn't change in any way if you use a different convention.

Comment: @NateEldredge right, exactly.

Comment: @NikWeaver so we cannot have a measure theory with $\infty \cdot 0 = \infty$? I don't see how do you preclude it?